# What is Kestrel (vs IIS / Express)

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

What is the kestrel web server and how does it relate to IIS / IIS Express?

I come from developing apps on IIS Express and hosting them on an IIS web server. With ASP.NET Core I have a dependency on `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel` and my startup has `.UseServer("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel")`. But when I run my website, I still get the IIS Express icon in the system tray. Someone asked me if I was using IIS Express or Kestrel and I didn't know what to say!

I don't have any cross-platform requirements as I develop on a PC and host in Azure, so I'm confused if I even `need` Kestrel, but it doesn't seem like there's an alternative - even the simplest samples use Kestrel.

Comment: When you have a question about this new technology, start at the GitHub page for the projects in question and look at their Wikis. You'd run across this [Servers wiki page](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Servers) for the ASP.NET repo.

Comment: Of course, then you run into stuff like `This document is now out of date. For up-to-date ASP.NET Core documentation go to: http://docs.asp.net`. Oops.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42382317/how-can-i-disable-the-iis-express-launch-profile-for-asp-net-core?

Answer (score 157, accepted):

> What is Kestrel

It's a full blown web server. You can run your ASP.NET Core application using just Kestrel.

> But when I run my website, I still get the IIS Express icon in the system tray

In your ASP.NET application, probably in the `wwwroot` directory, you'll see a web.config that contains this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
    <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform processPath="%DNX_PATH%" arguments="%DNX_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" startupTimeLimit="3600"/>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This is the HttpPlatformHandler. Essentially, what this does is forward *all* requests to Kestrel. IIS Express (and IIS for that matter) will not run ASP.NET themselves anymore. Instead, they will act as proxies that simply pass requests and responses back and forth from Kestrel. There is still advantages of using IIS, specifically it gives you security configuration, kernel-level caching, etc.

Comment: This answer is a little bit out-of-date due to the introduction of ASP.NET Core Module (instead of HttpPlatformHandler). I offered an alternative answer with more stories and related products as well.

Answer (score 326):

I'd like to offer an alternative answer, with some history, so that you might understand why Kestrel comes, even if you only use Windows and IIS.

At the very beginning of ASP.NET development before year 2000, clearly Microsoft created two pieces to host ASP.NET WebForms apps,

- Cassini, later became ASP.NET Development Server in Visual Studio. It is a fully managed web server written in C# based on `HttpListener`. Of course, since it was for development only, many features were never implemented. As Microsoft made the source code of Cassini available for the public, there are third parties who forked the code base and added more features, which started the Cassini family.
- ASP.NET support on IIS (revision 1). Because IIS was 4.0 and 5.0/5.1 at that time, which has nothing like application pools, ASP.NET even has its own worker process (`aspnet_wp.exe`).

So to develop a web app, you use Cassini, and to deploy you use IIS.

- The introduction of application pools in IIS 6 required some changes on ASP.NET side, so `aspnet_wp.exe` became obsolete and replaced by `aspnet_isapi.dll`. That can be seen as ASP.NET support on IIS revision 2. So ASP.NET apps are being hosted in IIS worker processes `w3wp.exe`.
- The introduction of integrated pipeline in IIS 7 and above required further changes, which replaced `aspnet_isapi.dll` with `webengine4.dll`. That can be seen as ASP.NET support on IIS revision 3. ASP.NET and IIS pipelines are unified.

You can see ASP.NET has become much more complex and tightly integrated with IIS, so Cassini started to show its age, and gradually was replaced by IIS Express (a user mode lite IIS).

Thus, in many cases, when people blame that IIS is slow, they should blame ASP.NET in fact. IIS itself without ASP.NET is pretty fast and stable, while ASP.NET was not developed with enough performance metrics in mind (as WebForms focuses quite a lot of productivities and RAD).

Then in November 2014, ASP.NET 5 (later renamed to ASP.NET Core) was announced and became a cross platform technology. Obviously Microsoft needed a new design to support Windows, macOS, and Linux, where all major web servers, nginx/Apache (or other web servers) should be considered besides IIS.

I think many would agree that Microsoft learned quite a lot from NodeJS, and then designed and developed Kestrel (based on `libuv` initially but might move to other technology soon). It is a light-weight web server like Cassini initially, but later more features are being added (like another answer commented, much more features so can be treated as a full web server). Though fully managed (some native dependencies exist), it is no longer a toy web server like Cassini.

Then why cannot you just use Kestrel? Why IIS Express and potentially IIS, nginx, or Apache are still needed? That primarily is a result of today's internet practice. Most web sites use reverse proxies to take requests from your web browsers and then forward to the application servers in the background.

- IIS Express/IIS/nginx/Apache are the reverse proxy servers
- Kestrel/NodeJS/Tomcat and so on are the application servers

Another answer already showed a link to Microsoft documentation, so you can take a look.

Microsoft developed HttpPlatformHandler initially to make IIS a good enough reverse proxy for Java/Python and so on, so planned to use it for ASP.NET Core. Issues started to appear during development, so later Microsoft made ASP.NET Core Module specifically for ASP.NET Core. That's ASP.NET support on IIS revision 4.

Starting from ASP.NET Core 2.2, ASP.NET Core Module for IIS (version 2) can host .NET Core environment inside IIS worker process (`w3wp.exe`), quite similar to ASP.NET 2.x/4.x. This mode is called ["IIS in-process hosting"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.2#in-process-hosting-model). It can be considered as ASP.NET support on IIS revision 5.

Well, quite lengthy, but I hope I put all necessary pieces together and you enjoy reading it.

One recent update (Jan 2023) is that ASP.NET Core/Kestrel can be used to host reverse proxy functionalities itself, as [the open source YARP project revealed](https://microsoft.github.io/reverse-proxy/).

Kestrel/YARP is now widely used inside Microsoft Azure to replace IIS ARR in many scenarios as reported, so literally now you can host your own production web apps with Kestrel/YARP without any other web server (IIS/nginx/Apache) in front as well.

> For other interesting history posts I wrote, you might [visit this site](https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/categories/history/).

Comment: Nice answer. But you cannot simply say that using kestrel with IIS is 'result of today's internet practice'. There are many rationales of using a reverse proxy. Would have been good to mention a few here.

Comment: "There are many rationales of using a reverse proxy" belongs to its own question and answer. Usually people can find good resources by asking Google, so I didn't append that to this already-long-enough answer.

Comment: To clarify, Node.js is just the runtime. An application server for Node.js would be PM2, if you're planning to go standalone, but for more robust deployments, you may want to use Passenger, then combine either of those two with an Nginx reverse proxy.

Comment: This is not a particularly clear answer. It could benefit from a thorough grammatical and content revision.

Answer (score 17):

From ms docs at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?tabs=aspnetcore2x

> Kestrel is a cross-platform web server for ASP.NET Core based on
> libuv, a cross-platform asynchronous I/O library. Kestrel is the web
> server that is included by default in ASP.NET Core project templates.
>
> You can use Kestrel by itself or with a reverse proxy server, such as
> IIS, Nginx, or Apache. A reverse proxy server receives HTTP requests
> from the Internet and forwards them to Kestrel after some preliminary
> handling.

---

#### UPDATE: .net core 2.1, Kestrel uses managed sockets instead of libuv

From asp.net core 2.1 docs at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.1#transport-configuration

> With the release of ASP.NET Core 2.1, Kestrel's default transport is
> no longer based on Libuv but instead based on managed sockets.

Answer (score 15):

1. Multiple apps on the same port is not supported in Kestrel.
2. Windows Authentication does not exist on Kestrel.
3. Request Filtering is much more fully featured in IIS.
4. Mime Type Mapping is much better in IIS.
5. HTTP access logs aren’t collected in Kestrel.

Comment: Also "[Kestrel server don't currently offer built-in compression support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/response-compression?view=aspnetcore-7.0)"

Comment: This does not answer the question that was asked, but rather gives a list of some specific differences between the two services.

Comment: It does address the 'real question behind the question' -- why would I use one over the other. So imho it's a more useful response than some of the more direct answers!