# How to prevent launchSettings.json from being created in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, .net-core

VS 2017 creates a file for ASP.NET Core MVC projects, called `launchSettings.json`, which contains information about IIS Express and Kestrel AMAIK.

We host our projects in IIS even on development machines, thus we don't really need these files.

We delete them, yet they keep coming back and each time we open up a solution, they show up.

Is there a way to prevent VS from creating those files?

Comment: VS may have to use the file. I don't see the issue in having the file in there. you can always set up a publish which is not going to have the file. does it show after publish?

Comment: @NevilleNazerane, the reason we don't want it to be there is because we have more than 100 check-in policies for the sake of quality, and it usually messes with those policies. Sure it's not preventive for our work, but continuous improvement's spirit suggests that we do improvements always and in all sizes.

Comment: well if you are talking about tfs, i guess you can remove it from source or exclude from project (can't recreate the file with it still on server). Also won't emptying of the file help? because it seems like something like .csproj file that vs requires

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I disable the IIS Express launch profile for ASP.NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42382317/how-can-i-disable-the-iis-express-launch-profile-for-asp-net-core)

Answer (score 18):

As per https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/652195/view.html - just add the following property to the .csproj:
`<NoDefaultLaunchSettingsFile>true</NoDefaultLaunchSettingsFile>`