# In F#, .Net Core, The project doesn't know how to run the profile IIS Express

Tags: f#, iis-7

I am using Visual Studio 16.7.7.

I have a postgreSQL database running through a WCF/IIS 7 server on my local machine. All works well with .NET Framework. After moving my F# code to .Net Core 3.1, I created a ConnectedService.json in a C# project that now has the following:

```
{
  "ProviderId": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ConnectedService.Wcf",
  "Version": "15.0.40203.910",
  "ExtendedData": {
    "inputs": [
      "http://sager:9003/MedicalServiceHost.svc"
    ],
    "collectionTypes": [
      "System.Array",
      "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2"
    ],
    "namespaceMappings": [
      "*, MedicalService"
    ],
    "references": [
      "Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors, {Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf, 1.1.19}"
    ],
    "targetFramework": "netcoreapp3.1",
    "typeReuseMode": "All"
  }
}
```

Then in the F# code I have:

```
module FsNetwork =
    let context = new MedicalService.MedicalServiceClient(new BasicHttpBinding(MaxReceivedMessageSize =2147483647L), new EndpointAddress("http://sager:9003/MedicalServiceHost.svc"))

    /// Get the office schedule for the tableDate.
    let GetScheduleAsync (tableDate : DateTime) =
        async {
            let! data = context.GetOfficeScheduleAsync(tableDate) |> Async.AwaitTask
            return data |> Seq.map(fun q -> {
                Visit.lastName = q.lastname
                firstName = q.firstname
                birthDate = q.birthdate 
                appointmentTime = q.appointment_time
                tservice = q.service_time
                postingTime = q.posting_time
                chartNumber = q.chart_number
                })                  
          }
          |> Async.StartAsTask
```

where I increased the MaxReceivedMessageSize.

Now upon startup I get:
**The project doesn't know how to run the profile IIS Express**

Which is odd since I'm running IIS 7 locally.

How do I fix this error?

Thank you.

Addendum:

After wasting a good deal of time and hair, I happened upon [How to disable the iis express launch profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42382317/how-can-i-disable-the-iis-express-launch-profile-for-asp-net-core)

I had not before noticed the "Express" on the visual studio display:

[image: Visual Studio]

When the drop-down on the "Express" is used, and changed back to my startup project -- StargateIX, then recompiled and run--ALL WORKS CORRECTLY!

So, what is this drop-down box all about?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drop-down box is used to select the carrier to run the application, and IIS Express is one of the options. In the drop-down list, you can choose to use IIS Express or other to run the application. When using IIS Express, you can also choose which browser to view the running result. At the same time, breakpoint debugging can also be opened through it.

IIS Express is a lightweight IIS, it has most of the functions of IIS, eliminating the need to repeatedly publish to IIS when debugging applications, more convenient to use and integrated in the visual studio.

[IIS and IIS Express](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express/iis-express-overview#iis-express-and-iis)

Comment: What is a "carrier" to run the application?  Also, if IIS Express is already built into visual studio, how does it not know how to run it?  Thanks.

Comment: Application should run in the application pool, and applciation pools are in IIS, it just like a container.