# How to run .Net MVC in IIS (vs using `dotnet run` for testing locally)

Tags: c#, .net, iis, .net-core

So this is a C#-based .Net WebApp for a client on an Azure deployment on their network.

Testing locally, I can do `dotnet run` and test on `http://localhost:5000` fine, but in the final environment, it'll need to be served by IIS.  I believe `dotnet run` (Kestrel) and IIS have a way of talking to each other (there is a method called something like `.useIISIntegration` I believe).

But I'd like to skip any deployment script that requires I `dotnet run` to start the application if possible, but let IIS handle all of that.  Once deployed, is `dotnet run` absolutely necessary?  How does IIS handle it directly, if possible?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/

Comment: You might get some basic ideas from my answer for another question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35639205/what-is-kestrel-vs-iis-express/46878663#46878663 Like the other comment indicated, Microsoft already documented it well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that for your purpose you can simply:

- run *dotnet publish*
- create an application in IIS against the program
- create an application pool and start it.

Don't forget to install the SDK/Hosting bundle in the destination server otherwise IIS will not be able to run it.