# Asp.Net Core application using the Kestrel web server instead of IIS, why?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am developing Ap.Net Code web application, I am using the below setting in the csproj file. When I run the application using visual studio I can see dotnet.exe running in the task manager, but it should be w3wp.exe or iisexpress.exe in case of InProcess hosting. So what could be the reason behind it?

```
<AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
```

CSProj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.8" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Why should it be w3wp or iisexpress? Neither of those are cross-platform, which .NET Core is.

Comment: As I know when kestrel comes in to the picture only if it is OutOfProcess

Comment: You should probably read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35639205/what-is-kestrel-vs-iis-express) QnA.

Comment: You can choose whether your application should use IIS or Kestrel as its webserver in your Program.cs. Add the line `webBuilder.UseIIS()` in the `CreateWebHost` method to use IIS. But the runtime will always be `dotnet.exe` as you are writing code for the .NET Core

Comment: And probably [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=windows) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.2) Microsoft documentation page

Comment: I have gone through this link. according to this it should be w3wp or iisexpress. Please clarify if I am wrong.  https://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.com/2019/01/aspnet-core-in-process-hosting.html

Comment: Did you call `UseIIS()` or `CreateDefaultBuilder()`? Check that your project aligns with the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

Comment: @all If you watch this video, it's printing the Process name as iisexpress. But I am getting dotnet instead of this. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ydR2jd3ZaEA

Comment: Even if IIS is hosting, it will be hosting something like "dotent YourApplication.dll", when using dotnet core.

Comment: Share us your full csproj content. Do you develop with asp.net core 2.2? I made a test with default asp.net core mvc template, it works correctly to return `iisexpress` when I start from VS.

Comment: @TaoZhou updated the question with csproj file, the target framework is .net core 2.0

Comment: @viveknuna .NET Core 2.0 was a short-term release that went out of support after a few months. The long-term support version is 2.1. You definitely need to upgrade, either to 2.1 or 2.2, the latest short-term version, which also provides in-process hosting in IIS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For hosting in process feature, it is in `netcoreapp2.2`.

For previous feature, it is `out-of-process hosting`.

This could be found from [IIS in-process hosting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/release-notes/aspnetcore-2.2?view=aspnetcore-2.2#iis-in-process-hosting)

For testing this feature, you could try to create Asp.Net Core MVC 2.2 template.

If you want to check this feature in your current project, you need to migrate your current project to Asp.Net Core 2.2, for migration, you could refer [Migrate from ASP.NET Core 2.1 to 2.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/21-to-22?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: so it means in process feature is not present in .net core 2.0? is it documented anywhere?

Comment: @viveknuna Yes.

Comment: is it documented anywhere?

Comment: @viveknuna Please check [IIS in-process hosting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/release-notes/aspnetcore-2.2?view=aspnetcore-2.2#iis-in-process-hosting)

Comment: thank you, please mention the documentation in the answer, so that it can help others also.